# How do I send a specific (generated) variable in PHP to a JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP page that generates different invoices in a search function and each invoice has a table that gets shown when the user clicks on a button (via JavaScript). The question is how to send a specific button id to the JavaScript.  This is my code so far.

```
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="newDisplay()" style="padding: 5px;width: 90px;" value="Add Receipt">';
```

And

```
$idName = 'myForm' . $job['id'];
echo '<table style="display:none;width:100%;" id="' . $idName . '">';
```

Then the JavaScript is:

```
function newDisplay() {
        document.getElementById('<?php echo $idName; ?>').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

If a button is generated for each invoice, is there a way to send the element ID plus the invoice ID so that only the one specific table gets shown? I can concatenate the job id to the myForm, but how would I check that with the JavaScript?

EDIT: I tried the concatenation, but the JavaScript picks up the last one.

Comment: You could add an id like this (note that id's should be unique on the page) `$id = 1;
echo '<input id="' . $id .'" type="submit" onclick="newDisplay()" style="padding: 5px;width: 90px;" value="Add Receipt">';
`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I tried was creating a variable where I concatenated the myForm with the job ID number and then put a PHP echo in the JavaScript, but it only gets the last one for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do something like this

```
 echo '<input type="submit" id="' . $id .'" data="" onclick="newDisplay(this.id)" style="padding: 5px;width: 90px;" value="Add Receipt">';
```

And in javascript

```
function newDisplay(id) {
//doanything with the id
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

You can also access any extra attribute you want to send in js like

```
function newDisplay(id) {
 let my_attr=$("#"+id).attr("data");
    //doanything with the id
            document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'block';
        }
```

If your id is numeric then you might need to append any alphabet or word before that like

```
echo '<input type="submit" id="my_' . $id .'" data="" onclick="newDisplay(this.id)" style="padding: 5px;width: 90px;" value="Add Receipt">';
```

And then in js you can access the id like

```
function newDisplay(id) {
var myid=id.split("_");
//doanything with the myid[1]
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: I am finding that only the first invoice's table shows up onclick. When I click on the other invoices, only the first one opens.  I need a way to find which invoice's button is being clicked on and only open that table.

Comment: I told you the way to send unique id to js from php ,rest you can configure accordingly @RivaPortman

Comment: Thank you. I just saw it now. I appreciate the help.